# How to scroll the page on load only if the user does not scroll himself?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, scroll

I have a simple jquery script which improves user experience and scrolls to page title on page load.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
     $('html, body').animate({
         'scrollTop':   $('#title').offset().top
     }, 1000);
});
```

However, I want this script to run only if the user stayed at the top during the page load and did not scroll the page himself. If the user scrolled down during the page load, the script shouldn't do any work and should not interrupt the user's behavior on site.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: So is #title not at the top of the web page?  If it is at the top, won't the page already be at the top when first loaded?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use jQuery's [**`.scrollTop()`**](http://api.jquery.com/scrollTop/) to check the current scroll position:

```
$(function() {
  if($(window).scrollTop() == 0) {
     $('html, body').animate({
       'scrollTop': $('#title').offset().top
     }, 1000);
  }
})
```

Comment: Exactly what I wanted. Thx Dmytro!